# Make browser back button close jQuery UI dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, back-button

What would be the simplest way to go about making the browser back button close a jQuery UI dialog?

I know there are plugins for 'virtual addresses' with hash tags, but I'm after something simpler than this — the app I am building is predominantly a classic web app but with a few modal ajax forms.

Comment: How does the user go forward in the first place? Is there a hash change involved?

Comment: Do you mean instead of going back a page, it closes the dialog? Seems like you are trying to override the default behavior of the browser back button.

Comment: At the moment there is no hash change involved

Comment: @jk. Yes, I am trying to change the default behavior - I feel that because a modal form essentially hides the current page and presents the user with a completely new dialog it would be more natural for the back button to bring them back to the 'page' they could see before. Most users don't know the difference between  ajax requests and normal requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onhashchange` event? This is only supported on some browsers, but there are plugins that implement it on others. E.g. http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Comment: That looks spot on - I just didn't really want to add jQuery address and another 10kb of script for a single feature - this is perfect, 0.8kb